# Cartesian axes with tkz-Euclide have missing tick marks

Tags: latex, tikz

I just started using tkz-Euclide and tried to create a XY coordinate axes.
According to the tkz-Euclide manual, the following code creates it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \tkzInit[xmax=4,ymax=4]
    \tkzDrawX\tkzDrawY
    \tkzDefPoint(-1+2,sqrt(4)){O}
    \tkzDefPoint({3*ln(exp(1))},{exp(1)}){A}
    \tkzDefPoint({4*sin(pi/6)},{4*cos(pi/6)}){B}
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,B,A)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the manual, the x-axis and y-axis have tick marks for every unit, but after running this code on my laptop I only get the axis without the tick marks.

I have been reading the manual but I have not found any clue about how to show them.

Any ideas?

I am using TeXLive 2022 and tkz-euclide v4.2 on Linux

Thanks

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Thanks for the update! This problem seems to start somewhere during 2021. It still works with `2021.9.30`, but already fails with the fully updated version of TL2021 (which was frozen in spring 2022). I suggest that you contact the package author. Contact details are included in the package documentation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the possible bug should be reported to the author of the package